# using different worksheet as a crossreference to filter values in sheet 1

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am having trouble conceptualising a way to solve this problem. I want to filter out invalid values of sheet 1, column F, based on a crossreference of valid values in sheet 2.

I have no experience using filters in excel, but perhaps this is a good opportunity to use this functionality.

The difficulty is that sheet 1 has multiple trials (column c), and each trial has multiple valid values as shown in these screenshots.

Sheet 1.
[image: sheet 1]

Sheet 2.
[image: sheet 2]

Aside from using the filtering functionality, which I am unfamiliar with, I was thinking of creating a dictionary object and using Column C in sheet 1, or column A in sheet 2 as the key, but then I'm not sure how to make the program check multiple values, without using a big long nested loop iterating through every cell of sheet 2 as well column F in sheet 1.

The basic task I want to achieve is:
`For trial #, sheet 1, if column F =/= (a value in row #, sheet 2), then delete row.`

**Update:**
I have tried this code, which returns a runtime 1004 appication or object defined error on the "for each" line:

```
Sub RemoveNonMatch()

    Dim rngDel As Range, rw As Range

    For Each rw In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("full test").Range("B7:Q" & lastrow).Rows
        If Not IsMatch(rw.Cells(3).Value, rw.Cells(6).Value) Then
            If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = Application.Union(rngDel, rw)
            Else
                Set rngDel = rw
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
    'remove any non-matches
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.Delete
End Sub


Function IsMatch(TrialNum, AreaNum) As Boolean
    Dim t, a, rv
    rv = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AOI crossref")
        'try to find TrialNum in the first column
        t = Application.Match(TrialNum, .Columns(1), 0)
        If Not IsError(t) Then
            'try to find AreaNum in the m'th row
            a = Application.Match(AreaNum, .Rows(t), 0)
            If Not IsError(a) Then rv = True 'match!
        End If
    End With
    IsMatch = rv
End Function
```

[Here is a sample of the data I am using.](http://www.filedropper.com/fulltest)

Comment: (1) You have not defined `lastrow` or given it a value. (2) since you've defined your range as from ColB to ColQ, `rw.Cells(3)` is "Event name" (colD) and not "Trial name" (ColC).  Same issue for Area

Comment: "fixed" version of your file: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/15526711/full%20test%20TW.xlsm  BTW it's best when sharing a file to remove all code not relevant to the specific question - this way I don't have to review multiple modules before I make the decision to enable macros on your file.  And many people will not even download a file which has code.

Comment: @TimWilliams glad you posted that fix, as I fixed what you suggested and got it running, but it was deleting columns B to D. Looking at your code, it must have been how I defined the range or lastrow. anyway, thanks for the heads-up about the macro files. I also added some content to the AOI crossref sheet, but this looks good. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub RemoveNonMatch()

    Dim rngDel As Range, rw As Range

    For Each rw In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2I100").Rows 'or whatever...
        If Not IsMatch(rw.Cells(3).Value, rw.Cells(6).Value) Then
            If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngDel = Application.Union(rngDel, rw)
            Else
                Set rngDel = rw
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
    'remove any non-matches
    If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.Delete
End Sub


Function IsMatch(TrialNum, AreaNum) As Boolean
    Dim t, a, rv
    rv = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
        'try to find TrialNum in the first column
        t = Application.Match(TrialNum, .Columns(1), 0)
        If Not IsError(t) Then
            'try to find AreaNum in the m'th row
            a = Application.Match(AreaNum, .Rows(t), 0)
            If Not IsError(a) Then rv = True 'match!
        End If
    End With
    IsMatch = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, Tim. I tried using this code, changing the sheet name in the sub to `("full test").Range("B7:T" & lastrow)` and the sheet in the function to `("AOI crossref")`. It's giving me a runtime error 1004 on `For Each rw` line.

Comment: I forgot to add .Rows to the end of that line (see edit).  Try it with that fix.  If that doesn't fix it then if you can share some sample data I will test/debug.

Comment: alright I've edited my question with the code I tried, and provided a link for sample data. The .rows thing didn't work.